# Can there be a function that's even and odd at the same time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, even-and-odd-functions

I woke up this morning and had this question in mind. Just curious if such function can exist.

Comment: In case anyone has forgotten what “even” and “odd” functions are, $f$ is even if $f(x) = f(-x)$ and odd if $-f(x) = f(-x)$. See also [Wikipedia on even and odd functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions).

Comment: You might find it interesting that I often used to ask this as an extra credit question on precalculus tests when even/odd function properties were covered, typically worth an extra 3 points on a 100 point scale (so a score of 103/100 was possible). I'd usually get about 2 to 5 students getting the extra points (out of a total of maybe 25-35 students) in a U.S. college precalculus class, and about half the class getting the extra points in U.S. honors level high school classes I used to teach.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Others have mentioned that $f(x)=0$ is an example. In fact, we can prove that it is the *only* example of a function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (i.e a function which takes in real values and outputs real values) that is both odd and even. Suppose $f(x)$ is any function which is both odd and even. Then $f(-x) = -f(x)$ by odd-ness, and $f(-x)=f(x)$ by even-ness. Thus $-f(x) = f(x)$, so $f(x)=0.$

Comment: Of course, one could argue that restrictions of the constant $0$ function to different domains symmetric about the origin are different functions, set-theoretically speaking.

Comment: @CameronBuie That is true, I will make my answer more precise to indicate this. Thank you.

Comment: Funny, I never thought of f(x) = 0 as a possibility. Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 35):

If $K$ is a field of characteristic 2, *every* function $K\to K$ is both even and odd.

Comment: i'm sorry, wouldn't that be "unequal to 2"?

Comment: @Auke: No. I won't spoil the joke by spelling it out, sorry.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need a field, any ring of characteristic 2 will do.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, oh, I am sorry, I misread your answer, you are completely right :) nice one

Comment: This is a wonderful answer!

Comment: +1 That's a wonderful answer with which to start my day. Thanks you!

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: @Agos: Have a look at [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29), and try to work out the consequences of the characteristic being 2.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thanks. I lol'd.

Comment: If $K=\{0,1\}$ then how is the function $f(x) = x + 1$ both even and odd?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq $f(-1)=f(1)=-f(1)=0$ and $f(-0)=f(0)=-f(0)=1$. Perhaps what surprises you is that in characteristic 2, and odd function need not satisfy $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. The constant function $f(x) = 0$ satisfies both conditions.

Even:
$$
f(-x) = 0 = f(x)
$$

Odd:
$$
f(-x) = 0 = -f(x)
$$

Furthermore, it's the only real function that satisfies both conditions:

$$
f(-x) = f(x) = -f(x) \Rightarrow 2f(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0
$$

Answer (score 10):

**Hint** $\rm\ f\:$ is even and odd $\rm\iff f(x) = f(-x) = -f(x)\:\Rightarrow\: 2\,f(x) = 0.\:$ This is true if $\rm\:f = 0,\:$ but may also have other solutions, e.g. $\rm\:f = n\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z/2n =\:$ integers mod $\rm 2n,$ where $\rm\: -n \equiv n.$

Comment: +1, but note that your last $\iff$ applies (in the backwards, i.e. 'if' direction) only to $f(x) = -f(x)$, and not to the part where $f(-x)$ equals both of them.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write $\:\Rightarrow\: $ but it was lost in editing. Now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose  $f$   odd  an  even.  Let  $x \in D$   ( D  is  set  definition  of  $f$)  then  you  have  :  $  f(x)=f(-x)=-f(x)$.  What can you   conclude about $f$ ?

Answer (score 4):

As other people have mentioned already, the real function $f(x)$ which maps every real number to zero (i.e.$f(x) = 0 \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$) is both even and odd because  $$f(x) - f(-x) = 0 \space \space ,  f(x)+f(-x) = 0\space \forall x \in \mathbb{R} .$$ Also it is the only function defined over $\mathbb{R}$
to possess this property.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a Boolean ring and $X$ be an arbitrary set. Then every function $f:R\rightarrow X$ is both even and odd.

Comment: Say what........?

Comment: @bodacydo for example: any polynomial $P(x)\in R[x]$.

Comment: Thanks that is useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

I post this as an addendum to the awesome answers already present for this Q.

## Most trivial example:

For $f(x)=0$ we have:

$f(x)= 0 =-f(-x)$ ***Hence, Odd***

$f(x)= 0 =f(-x)$ ***Hence, Even***

## I was searching for an answer to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479619/280202).

$f(x) = \sin(x) + \sin(\pi + x)$

Here, the function is also even and odd at the same time **(another example or representation of the same)**. This is due to the value resulting in zero over the entire domain. So, it can be concluded that all the functions that have their $Range=\{0\}$ should be both even and odd at the same time despite their notation is of a **constant function**($f(x)=0$) or not.

**Another example,**

$f:\{1,-1\}\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = x^{2}-1$

$f(x) = 0$ for all values in the domain. So, it is both even and odd at the same time because while deciding even odd functions the *domain* to which the function is restricted by definition must be considered.

Answer (score 1):

We could also think even and odd functions as the following to get $f(x) = 0$ is a function that is both odd and even and go for some different functions:

*Odd functions* have graphs that are symmetric with respect to origin.

*Even functions* have graphs that are symmetric with respect to $y$-axis.

So, graph of $f(x) = 0$ satisfies both conditions, therefore it is both odd and even. Furthermore, we can define some piecewise functions that satisfies this condition using their graphs. For example, let $f(x)$ not defined on intervals $(-1,-2)$ and $(1,2)$; and whenever it is defined, $f(x) = 0$. Then $f(x)$ is, again, both even and odd. And as long as we define a piecewise function by removing intervals that are symmetric with respect to $y$-axis, and rest of the function $= 0$ even though they are not continuous.