# What do you call a function with the property $f(-x)=-f(x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

What is this property called? The domain and codomain of the function can be for example $\mathbb Z^n$, $\mathbb Q^n$ or $\mathbb R^n$ ($n>0$), potentially excluding the $0$ point. Examples: $f(x)=ax^k$ ($k$ being an odd integer), rotation in the plane around the origin by a fixed angle, $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)g(|x|)$ (where $g$ is some other function), etc.
I'm thinking of calling it "symmetric around $0$", does that sound right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions

Comment: Odd function. Google it.

Comment: I posted an answer which clarify the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call it [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions).

**P.S.** We call a function which satisfies $f(-x)=f(x)$ even function.

Comment: The oddest of all functions are those that are [both even and odd](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159493/can-there-be-a-function-thats-even-and-odd-at-the-same-time/159500#159500).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why the Japanese wikipedia? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, no meaning!

Comment: I edited it to English one.

Comment: The article says "let f(x) be a real-valued function of a real variable", is it ok to extend it to the sets I mentioned (or whatever context where "-x" makes sense)?

Comment: see the part of definition and examples of wiki.

Comment: Oh, you mean the part where it says "This includes additive groups, all rings, all fields, and all vector spaces", ok

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

**Just to clarify the definition:**

A function defined on a domain $D$ is called *odd function* if:

- $-x\in D$ whatever $x\in D$
- $f(-x)=-f(x)\;\;\forall x\in D$

Notice that **the first point is very important** although it is **often omitted**. For example the function
$$f\colon [0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto\sin x$$
isn't an odd function  since the first point isn't fullfiled.