# Both even function and odd function

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

I know that 0 is an even function and an odd function.
How can I prove f is both even and odd if and only if it is the constant 0 function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can there be a function that's even and odd at the same time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159493/can-there-be-a-function-thats-even-and-odd-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Even means $f(-x) = f(x)$ and odd means $f(-x) = -f(x)$ so both would mean $-f(x) = f(-x) =f(x)$ and $-f(x) = f(x)$ which means .... what?

Answer (score 1):

Well if $f$ is even then $f(-x) = f(x)$.  And if $f$ is odd then $f(-x)= -f(x)$.  And if $f$ is *both* even and odd then $f(x) = f(-x) =-f(x)$.

So....?

> So $f(x) = -f(x)$ so $2f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$.